# Moving vertex moves only the vertex, not the edges it is connected to

Tags: mesh, vertex-groups

I select one vertex on a 2D plane extrusions from another 2D plane and transform it along the X axis, but only the vertex moves and not the edges it is connected to. There is an Orange line connecting where the dot of the vertex is to its original spot.

I want to be able to move the vertex and the vertex stays connected to the edges (so it slightly deforms the edges).

I have Proportional editing off.
For reference, I am trying to follow these steps : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xQ8fOYTdqow

Comment: Can you include screenshots?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I was not pressing G AFTER selecting the vertex I wanted to move.
I was just selecting the vertex and moving it.
Pressing G then the vertex I want to move made it work as intended.